# Como justificar un texto largo en un <td> <table> de PHP/HTML para DomPDF

Tags: php, html, dompdf

Ya he probado align="justify" word-wrap white-space, pero nada me sigue apareciendo un indentado en todas las lineas luego de la primera.

[image: Este es un ejemplo de lo que me sucede con cada <td> luego de mandar la impresión con DOMPDF]
Y este es el codigo
[image: Y este es el codigo]

Comment: Estimado, bienvenido a StackOverflow, por favor el código que quieras compartir no lo debes compartir en imagenes ya que será mal recibido por la comunidad. Cambia tu código y evita que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías mostrar el código que usas para poder ayudarte?

Comment: ¿Has probado de utilizar el estilo `min-width: 100px` para redimensionar el tamaño de las celdas? Al imprimir un PDF no tiene por que mantener un aspecto responsivo.

Answer (score 0):

> Tuve el mismo problema y busqué la solución por días, incluso semanas, sé que tal vez sea tarde para ti pero no para los que se puedan encontrar con este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo único que hice fue agregar esta línea en mi controlador y todo funcionó de maravilla:

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf();

$dompdf->set_option('dpi', 1800);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No olvides explicar qué hace el código. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta.